# [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object

Tags: ios, json, heroku, parse-platform, heroku-api

I'm trying to set up my iOS app so I can use the parse database on heroku. In my app I wrote:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore.
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    let parseConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration(block: { (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "insta95222295"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "asdfsdfj@#$543sd"
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "https://insta9522.herokuapp.com/parse"

    })

    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfiguration)
```

and when I run it, I get the following error:

```
>Object has been saved. 
>2016-10-14 00:50:49.984 ParseStarterProject-Swift[9199:231387] [Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Heroku dashboard, in Settings tab, make sure you have set the `PARSE_MOUNT` to `/parse`

[image]